# fabric context manager with sudo

Tags: python, fabric, contextmanager

Is it possible to have a context manager that just keeps the state of the previous `run` execution. In code:

## EDIT: Not a working solution, something I expected

```
with sudo('. myapp'): #this runs a few things and sets many env variables
    run('echo $ENV1') # $ENV1 isn't set because the sudo command ran independently
```

I am trying to run several commands but want to keep state between each command ?

I tried using the prefix context manager but it doesn't work with the shell_env context manager: When running this code

```
with shell_env(ENV1="TEST"):
    with prefix(". myapp"):
          run("echo $ENV2")
```

I expected my `ENV` to be set then run my application which should have set `env2` but the prefix runs before the shell_env ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't really understand the question asked here. Could you give a little more detail in what you are trying to accomplish. However I tried the same thing (`with sudo('. myapp)`) you did which threw an `AttributeError __exit__` exception.

Finally I've tried the to use prefix to source the bash file and executing a sudo command line within this context, which works just fine.

```
@fab.task
def trythis():
    with fab.prefix('. testenv'):
        fab.sudo('echo $ENV1')
```

When executing the task I get the following output.

```
[host] Executing task 'trythis'
[host] sudo: echo $ENV1
[host] out: sudo password: 

[host] out: testing
[host] out: 


Done.
Disconnecting from host... done.
```

Comment: You're right in that the first example will not work but wanted to display what type of state execution I was expecting. I will update the question to reflect that. My second question with setting the shell_env before running the prefix as answered by @zmo was what I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

```
with shell_env(ENV1="TEST"):
    with prefix(". myapp"):
          run("echo $ENV2")
```

> *I expected my ENV to be set then run my application which should have set env2 but the prefix runs before the shell_env ?*

Given [fabric's documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/context_managers.html) the code you've written will generate:

```
export ENV1="TEST" && . myapp && echo $ENV2
```

Given that `myapp` creates `ENV2`, your code should work the way you want it to work, though not all shell interpret the dot operator the same way, using `source` is always a better idea.

```
with shell_env(ENV1="TEST"):
    with prefix("source myapp"):
          run("echo $ENV2")
```

You may consider a bug in `myapp` though, and/or double check that all path and working directory are correctly set.

Comment: I am still not able to verify the code generated. I may have output being disabled but the environment set by `shell_env` aren't being used in the following prefix